# JavaScript works no wrap but not onLoad with jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

So, I have code that works with no wrap, but doesn't work onLoad. Could somebody explain to me why this doesn't work?
I am trying to get this to work for my web app, but the JavaScript isn't working. However, when I plug it into fiddle, it works when I change from onLoad to no wrap.

```js
function zoomIn(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay0");
  element.className = "overlay";
  element.style.display = "inline-block";
  var img = document.getElementById("imgZoom0");
  var posX = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - img.offsetLeft;
  var posY = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - img.offsetTop;
  element.style.backgroundPosition=(-posX*2)+"px "+(-posY*4)+"px";

}

function zoomOut() {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay0");
  element.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.overlay{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:350px;
  height:200px;
  display:none;
  background-image:url('http://ginger-mum.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/3633-1269758855-0da5042c33400a811a5d766be4579cb8.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<img id="imgZoom0" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)" onmouseout="zoomOut()" src="https://apparelpop.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/DEA411-AT.jpg" alt="Dea411 at" width="150" height="150" />
<div id=overlay0 onmousemove="zoomIn(event)"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by onLoad to no wrap?

Comment: function calls in inline js need to be global, by defining them in onload they are not global

Comment: how are my functions defined in onload?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use `onLoad` option the code is wrapped in a load event handler.....something like:

```
window.onload = function(){
  // your code  ends up here    
}
```

So the scope of your functions are not in global window space where they need to be to be able to call them from the dom